# Issues with SendKeys

Tags: c#

Wondering what is the problem with SendKeys? Or is it ok to use if you have no other choice?

Comment: Huh? Which SendKeys? What issue? The Form one? Or the scripting one?
For the Forms one - the .NET 2.0 version **won't work in Vista** (UAC) (.NET 3.0+ version must be used).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be much better off with [Ui Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Simulating user input generally indicates a hack, since the user interface is not an API (*application* interface), so its format is often inexact, subject to change and generally not intended to be used from code.

Sometimes, however, there is no other choice. Whether it's "OK" or not depends on what the alternatives are.